# adjusting column width based on show/hide CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 columns in a in a div row. The one on the left is my main content and the one on the right is chatroom. I want my users to be able to minimize and open the chatroom I know how to do this part. However when chatroom is Open i want my left column to be col-lg-10 and when chatroom is closed i want it to become col-lg-12. How can I acheive this?

Comment: 3 lines of jQuery. Mind showing the minimal code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery (I see you use Bootstrap already) is quite straightforward:

```
$(".buttonToggleChat").on("click", function(){
   $(".someSpecificClassColumn").toggleClass("col-lg-10 col-lg-12");
   // ^^ the same selector you want to toggle 10/12 lg classes
});
```

Comment: I was hoping to acheive it without jquery but I'll try and let you know thanks

Comment: @HiradRoshandel you're welcome